# Angular 2 RC3 + Router Path Variables with special characters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I just upgraded to the new router from RC2. One of my components has a path like:

```
/login/:email/:token
```

Now when I enter a url like `/login/myemail@gmail.com/myToken` this component is not picked up. I figured out it has something to do with the special characters `@` and `.` in my email address. I drop them it works.

With javascripts `encodeUriComponent()` I can encode (and then decode in the component) the email but it only does it for the `@`, not the `.` So it still doesnt work.

Why is this happening, and how can I go about passing my email into this path?

Answer (score 2):

There are some breaking changes in rc.4:

> http: The changes to Http's URLSearchParams serialization now prevent
>   encoding of these characters inside query parameters which were
>   previously converted to percent-encoded values @ : $ , ; + ; ? /
>
> The default encoding behavior can be overridden by extending
>   QueryEncoder, as documented in the URLSearchParams service.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

And these characters are also not encoded before rc.4:

> These are the characters that are not encoded: ! $ \' ( ) * + , ; A 9
>   - . _ ~ ? /

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html